# How to Pass Angular expression into Variable for Enum.GetName

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an angular expression `{{item.status}}` which is an Enum value. I want to put it in a variable and get the name like

```
<span>@Enum.GetName(typeof(PeriodStatus), statusVal)</span>
```

Please how can I do this?

Comment: You can't.  Razor views are rendered server-side and angular templates are parsed after the html is already brought down.

Comment: @DavidL Okay. How do you suggest I make the name of the enum value `item.status` to display the name and not the value please? I've been on this for 2 days now.

Comment: It's unclear what you're actually trying to accomplish.  Where is the data coming from?  When do you expect it to be rendered?  What is the relationship between the serverside enum and your angular template?

Comment: @DavidL The enum value is coming from my database. I'm trying to display some records in a table with a table grid. I get the data from my application business logic via and Angular script controller.

Comment: There are only two ways this can work.  1) you render the enum in the razor view because you are using razor models and you are retrieving the database record at the same time that you are rendering the view.  You don't need any Angular for this.  2) you are rendering raw html via the view and retrieving the database values via a service, which is then getting applied via angular model binding in the controller.  In that case, you WOULDN'T put anything in the view other than the angular syntax and you bind after the data came down via service.

Comment: @DavidL But If I render the enum in the razor view like that, it will display the integer value for the enum (1, 2 or 3) and that doesn't mean anything. Please can you show me how I can display the name instead?

Comment: There's nothing in your question that indicates that this would be the case.  If by name you mean "Enum value", such as Test = 1, then it should properly display "Test" if the statusVal propagated from the model is 1.  If you're talking about an attribute that you are applying to each enum value, that is an entirely different affair.  As is it is really impossible to tell what the actual problem is or how to help direct you.

Comment: @DavidL It's the integer that is stored in the database, so if I use an angular expression like this `item.status` it will display 1 and not "Test". Do you understand what I'm saying now?

Comment: Yes, I do.  You can't do that.  You need to convert it BEFORE it ever reaches the client.  Angular has no way to parse the data, so you'll need to make the conversion to a string via the C# code somewhere other than the view.